# Most Efficient Way to Join Massive/Small Datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I currently have a large RDD called `chartEvents` containing data of the form:

```
case class ChartEvent(patientID: String, itemID: String, chartTime: String, storeTime: String, value: String,
    valueNum: String, warning: String, error: String)
```

The data is coming from a 35 GB .csv file which I am parsing in using SQL:

```
CSVUtils.loadCSVAsTable(sqlContext, "data_unzipped/CHARTEVENTS.csv")
val chartEvents = sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |SELECT SUBJECT_ID, ITEMID, CHARTTIME, STORETIME, VALUE, VALUENUM, WARNING, ERROR
    |FROM CHARTEVENTS
  """.stripMargin)
  .map(r => ChartEvent(r(0).toString, r(1).toString, r(2).toString, r(3).toString, r(4).toString,
    r(5).toString, r(6).toString, r(7).toString))
```

I have a separate, very small (less than 100 rows) RDD called `featureMapping` of the form `RDD[(itemID, label)]` where these are both strings. What I am trying to do is filter down the `chartEvents` RDD to rows which only contain itemIDs in `featureMapping`. My current method is to perform an inner join of the two RDDs as follows:

```
val result = chartEvents.map{case event => (event.itemID, event)}.join(featureMapping)
```

However, I am noticing that this is on track to take several hours to run, and is using a massive amount of space in my `/user/<user>/appdata/local/temp` folder. Is there a more efficient way to perform this filtering? Would coding it into the sqlContext be faster?

Comment: see `Map-side join` using broadcast variables: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html#Introduction

Comment: @maasg, thanks for the feedback, seems to have improved the performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you register your tables in hive metastore you can set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`

from the [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html):

> Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be
>   broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this
>   value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. Note that currently
>   statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the
>   command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been
>   run.

Comment: Hive metastore is something I am unfamiliar with. Appreciate the link, I'll get reading up on it.